# Oracle Query: Get two most recently records for each document

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to get two most recently notes per each document from Oracle database.
The query is:

```
select a.doc_id, b.notes, b.post_ts
from tableA a, tableB b
where a.doc_id=b.doc_id(+)
order by doc_id, post_ts desc

doc_id  notes   post_ts
5743    Test 1  23-Aug-2010 10:25:03
5743    Test 2  14-Aug-2010 14:11:59
5743    Test 3  14-Aug-2010 13:56:20
6813    Test 4  12-Oct-2010 14:34:37
7543    Test 5  22-Apr-2014 17:02:23
7543    Test 6  22-Apr-2014 09:46:33
7543    Test 7  14-Mar-2014 12:17:58
```

The results should be:

```
doc_id  notes   post_ts
5743    Test 1  23-Aug-2010 10:25:03
5743    Test 2  14-Aug-2010 14:11:59
6813    Test 4  12-Oct-2010 14:34:37
7543    Test 5  22-Apr-2014 17:02:23
7543    Test 6  22-Apr-2014 09:46:33
```

Can I just write one sql to handle this case or I have to write a PL/SQL function? I know how to handle it for one document, but couldn’t figure out how to do for multiple documents.

Comment: why are you using an outer join if you want the 2 latest notes? in order to bring back the 2 latest notes for a doc_id, there must be notes begin with.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do this with `row_number()`

```
with x as (
    select
        a.doc_id,
        b.notes,
        b.post_ts,
        row_number() over (partition by a.doc_id order by b.post_ts desc) rn
    from
        tableA a
            left outer join
        tableB b
            on a.doc_id = b.doc_id

) select
    x.doc_id,
    x.notes,
    x.post_ts
from
    x
where
    rn in (1, 2)
order by
    x.doc_id,
    x.post_ts desc;
```

Comment: Thanks Laurence, I get what I need.

Comment: @tigerpuzzle, if it resolves your issue, mark it as the answer, so it will be clear for future readers.